# Add a "more citations needed" notice

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Currently, the commonly-used citations needed notice reads "This post does not cite **any** references or sources..."

Given the way it is used in practice, I think there should be another notice that says something like "This post should cite more references or sources...", to cover answers which make some claims that are not supported by citations, but otherwise do have citations.

It's rather offputting to see an answer which does have some citations (though perhaps not enough) tagged with a notice that says it has none at all.

Comment: Please note that the OP has improved the references and  I've consequently removed the offending banner. I've added it to this question *for reference*.

Answer (score 3):

You have my total support on this, and sorry for the wording on your answer: I've asked the wording to be improved on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126301/131112) in March, and have gotten 14 up votes and yet no official response.

My proposal is to make the notice say:

> This post does not cite enough valid references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

Comment: I'd make it more like "this post contains unreferenced significant claims", though that phrasing is a bit awkward. The number of citations doesn't really matter, the number of assertions that are backed up by cites or not is important.

Comment: @Fabian How about "There are significant claims in this post that are not backed by references"?

Comment: Why don't you both put down your ideas as answers?