# "This post does not cite any references or sources" while it does?

Tags: support, references, comments

My answer to question [Do desktop computers catch fire (often)?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26487/do-desktop-computers-catch-fire-often) has one reference:

[image]

No very much, I agree (and I clearly state that other figures are assumptions).

Is this an auto-generated flag with a threshold that my answer does not meet, or did a person overlook the link?

BTW I have now made the link longer to have it stand out better.

[Edited to add]

Now OddThinking adds a comment saying "This is an answer based purely on a theoretical model" which is indeed the case: I complete overlooked the word *estimated* in the abstract. On further investigation, the report is not even very clear on how the estimates were obtained.

The answer is now deleted.

My question remains:

*Is this an auto-generated flag with a threshold that my answer does not meet, or did a person [initially] overlook the link?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the banner, it's not automatic.

I understand the banner is misleading, but we add it on questions that do not have *enough* references. The reason is simple: you need to support your answer with references, not simply add *a* reference to tick a checkbox off a list, if you know what I mean.

We've requested a change of wording here: [Add a "more citations needed" notice](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/add-a-more-citations-needed-notice)